# counter function give me minus value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a counter function, the counter will run when user hold the button. The problem here is when user hold the button **decrement**, the counter will keep going even when the value hit **0**, and it give me the minus value, which is I don't want that.

I have give the condition for that case, but I think there's something wrong with my approach.

here's the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-lake-rbyqy6?file=/src/App.js)

Was wondering if there's something I missed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (value > 0) {
     setValue((prev) => prev - incrementBidValue);
  } else if (value === 0) {
  setValue(0);
}
```

Try replacing your code with below one,

```
setValue((prev) => (prev - incrementBidValue) <= 0 ? 0 : (prev - incrementBidValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just edit your `decrement()` function in which you decrement the `value` state. I added a ternary operation which checks if the prevValue - 0.1 is going to be greater or equal than 0, if so it will run the decrement function, otherwise it will return 0 and not go into any negative value. Here is the full code from your `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const timer = React.useRef(null);

  const increment = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => setValue((prev) => prev + 0.01), 10);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(
      // Here we check to see if the minus operation results in a negative value or not
      // if it is going to bigger or equal to 0 we will do the decrements
      // else we will return 0
      () => setValue((prev) => (prev - 0.01 >= 0 ? prev - 0.01 : 0)),
      10
    );
  };

  function timeoutClear() {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onMouseLeave={timeoutClear}
        onMouseUp={timeoutClear}
        onMouseDown={decrement}
      >
        Decrement
      </button>
      <span style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 600, margin: '0px 10px' }}>
        {value.toFixed(2)}
      </span>
      <button
        onMouseLeave={timeoutClear}
        onMouseUp={timeoutClear}
        onMouseDown={increment}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @ujuy,

Did you trying to implement a counter, that `increments` or `decrements` by a fixed amount when the user holds down a button? To prevent the counter from going below zero. You could add the condition when you set the `value` in `setValue` like this.

```js
const decrement = () => {
 timer.current = setInterval(() => {
  if (value > 0) {
   setValue((prev) => {
    let preValue = prev - 0.01
    if (preValue < 0) {
     return 0
    }
    return preValue
   })
  }
  if (0 >= value) {
   setValue(0)
  }
 }, 10)
}
```